# Error:The conflict is caused by: Spleeter 2.3.0 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0 Spleeter 2.1.0 depends on tensorflow==2.3.0 on Raspberry pi3 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi, spleeter

I am trying to write a bash script on a Raspberrypi 3B that includes the library 'Spleeter'.
I tried `pip install spleeter` but got the following error:
`The conflict is caused by: Spleeter 2.3.0 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0 Spleeter 2.1.0 depends on tensorflow==2.3.0`
and got the following additional message:

```
`To fix this you could try to: 1.Loosen the range of package version you've specified 2.Remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict`
```

I am not sure how to go about this. I tried to go for an older version of the package but the installation halts midway. I tried installing an older version of python as well. I was not successful. Any and all inputs/support are appreciated.

Comment: I don't know for this particular case but sometimes `pip install --upgrade pip` fixes such problems.

Comment: I got thrown the same error.

Comment: https://youtu.be/QLZWQlg-Pk0 This helped me